# Can we do something to commemorate Anne McCaffrey?

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

For those who haven't heard, the great Dragonlady has gone between.

Can SF maybe do something to commemorate her life and works? Even just a quick note in the banner?

Comment: Certainly a blog post by someone familiar with her work.

Comment: Honor her by reading her books and ask questions about it ;)

Answer (score 7):

Banner? Gods, no. (It's been done recently on Stack Exchange, and caused quite a bit of friction. Banners are for site-related announcements.)

Maybe an Anne McCaffrey book grant? (Note: I have not spoken to anyone at SE about this, I'm just tossing it in the air.) It would be nice to have a grant for written material for a change.

Comment: Friction? Really? Huh. People are strange, I guess.

Comment: @Martha Aye, they are.

Comment: What was the banner, and what was the friction caused?

Comment: @OghmaOsiris There was a banner on [so] after Steve Jobs died. It caused quite a stir on [metase] (I think the worst bits have been deleted), including [the expectation that every other deserving person would get one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109160/dennis-ritchie-goes-into-the-night-without-a-quote-on-stack-overflow). I think it's best to let bygones be bygones and not create a precedent here.

Comment: @Gilles: Sorry, but the co-inventor of Unix and C was not _every_ _other_ _person_. A banner for Jobs _may_ have been appropriate at [apple](http://apple.stackexchange.com/), but not at [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: @MartinSchröder He said *deserving* person. He wasn't claiming that Dennis Ritchie was in any way less deserving than Steve Jobs, or even defending the decisions made. He was merely relating incidents from the past, which, incidentally, is where they should remain.

Answer (score 3):

I should have mentioned this earlier sorry: if anyone wants to do a blog post they are most welcome, of course.  I'll ensure that it gets edited and published right away.

(I can't do this myself because the only time I've tried her books I didn't like them, so that's probably not a great obit' post).

Comment: go read Richard M Stallman's obit for Steve Jobs :)