# RIP Jerry Pournelle

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

[Jerry Pournelle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerry_Pournelle), the [first author to write a novel on a computer](https://www.theverge.com/2017/9/9/16279582/jerry-pournelle-science-fiction-author-writing-computers-obituary), passed away [September 8th](https://www.jerrypournelle.com/chaosmanor/passings/), at the age of 84.

He has a [long list of science fiction novels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerry_Pournelle#Bibliography), and he has his own tag here on SFF: [jerry-pournelle](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jerry-pournelle).

> “Dead. I had to be dead. But dead men don't think about death. What do dead men think about? Dead men don't think. I was thinking - but I was dead. That struck me as funny and set off hysterics. And then I'd get myself under control and go 'round and 'round with it again. Dead. This was like nothing any religion had ever taught. Not that I'd ever 'caught' any of the religions going around. But none had warned of this.”
>   <sub>― Jerry Pournelle, *Inferno* (courtesy of [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/author/quotes/39099.Jerry_Pournelle))</sub>

Comment: First I heard of it.  Somehow, SF writers don't wind up on Google News or Entertainment Tonight when they go.  Unless they're L. Ron Hubbard, of course...

Comment: I don't think L.Ron was on Google News when he died, since it didn't exist in 1986.  Maybe ET, although that's a bit of a stretch, too.

Comment: My first instinct was to downvote this as if that could make it not true. :-(