# In Memoriam: Len Wein (1948-2017)

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

September 10th was marked by the passing of [Len Wein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Len_Wein), the comic book writer known for his work on Swamp Thing and Wolverine (the two he co-created with various artists), and other things.

Although I don't pretend to know anything about his works in general, I am familiar with his work on *Watchmen* prequels - *Before Watchmen: Dollar Bill* one-shot and the *Before Watchmen: Ozymandias* miniseries. The latter in particular provides a great backstory for one of the best characters in *Watchmen*, and it's even more interesting since Wein was the editor of the original run of *Watchmen*.